# Chave estrangeira SQL

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados

Possuo duas tabelas em SQL e preciso realizar uma busca. As tabelas e os campos são:

Funcionários: 'codigo' e 'nomeFuncionario'
Equipe: 'codigoEquipe' e 'funcionarioRegistrado', onde 'funcionarioRegistrado' é ligado a 'codigo' da tabela Funcionarios;

O resultado exibido deve ser o 'códigoEquipe' da equipe selecionada e 'nomeFuncionario'.

Como faço essa pesquisa?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, considerando que `funcionarioRegistrado` é chave estrangeira de código, há algumas formas de se fazer a consulta, uma delas:

```
SELECT e.codigoEquipe, f.nomeFuncionario FROM Equipe e INNER JOIN Funcionarios ON e.funcionarioRegistrado = f.codigo;
```

Essa consulta retornará apenas os resultados onde há correspondência nas duas tabelas.

Se você quiser todos os registros de equipe, mesmo que não tenha funcionários `null`, você deve trocar o `INNER` por `LEFT`.

E se quiser todos os funcionários, mesmo que não tenham equipe, troca o `INNER` por `RIGHT`.

Comment: Faltou colocar o apelido na tabela _Funcionarios_ no momento de fazer o _INNER JOIN_

Answer (score 1):

Para isso é necessário utilizar o `JOIN` do SQL, que serve para consultar dados em mais de uma tabela ao mesmo tempo.

No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
SELECT equipe.codigoEquipe, funcionarios.nomeFuncionario FROM equipe INNER JOIN funcionarios ON equipe.funcionarioRegistrado = funcionarios.codigo;
```

Você pode também fazer uma abreviação das tabelas para ficar mais exuto, apelidando as tabelas assim:

```
SELECT e.codigoEquipe, f.nomeFuncionario FROM equipe e INNER JOIN funcionarios f ON e.funcionarioRegistrado = f.codigo;
```

Comment: E onde na querry eu colocaria o WHERE, para pesquisar exatamente pelo codigo da equipe?

Comment: Após o _Inner Join_, assim: 
`SELECT e.codigoEquipe, f.nomeFuncionario FROM equipe e INNER JOIN funcionarios f ON e.funcionarioRegistrado = f.codigo WHERE e.codigoEquipe = 2;`

Repare que coloquei o número 2 como código da equipe, mas no seu código você vai passar ele.